# Command window flashing only when os.system is being used

Tags: python, command-window

I have a weird issue on a friends machine where when they run my script, it only flashes the command window when it hits a line that does something with os.system. It seems to not show the command window at all otherwise. Not showing is fine, but my script does a large process and it causes the window to flash a lot.

Normally on my machine, when I open the script (that launches a gui with tkinter) the command window will open as well in the back. This is what I am trying to get my friends to do, but I do not know what would cause the command window to not show. Is there a setting within python somewhere that doesn't show the command window (unless of course it needs to run a process in it)?

Edit: Ok I did a really lame hack to fix this. Apparently all he .py files got associated with pythonw. I was unable to get this association changed (even going through the command prompt ASSOC) So I just did a silly renamed of the pythonw to old_pythonw, and renamed the python.exe to pythonw.exe. Yes, really silly but no time to argue with windows about file associations.

Comment: I believe `os.system` opens a cmd window to run run whatever you are running. You are running on MS Windows. This does not happen on *nix.

Comment: Ah yes, I am running on windows. If the command window displayed all the time it wouldn't open up another one just to run that, there would be no flashing. I am trying to figure out how to just open the command window while any .py is running. I think my friends .py files may be opening with pythonw

Comment: I don't think there is any way around it. `system` runs a new cmd whenever it's called. To avoid it, don't use `system`, use the `subprocess` module.